# How to align elements of a navigation bar to the right with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show the navigation bar items aligned to the right but it doesn't work for me this way. I put the ml-auto to the list class but it still shows me the items aligned to the left. How can I make it show me the navigation bar items aligned to the right?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              id="navbarDropdown"
              role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You can try like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                id="navbarDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using Angular, that works with components and there is no need to add anything else other than the body

Comment: Which bootstrap library you are using in angular ?

Comment: @duck_go19 You can try `justify-content-end` in your ul item div.

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS library

Comment: `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ">`

Comment: @duck_go19 updated the code. please have look

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work :'(

Comment: I used your code but the elements are not moved as I want :(

Comment: please check your bootstrap library probably the issue will be there. You can try to load bootstrap css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">` adding this to your index.html.

Comment: It was indeed the Bootstrap version that was giving me errors. Thank you very much for your help, it finally worked for me :')

Answer (score 0):

Hey duck_go19 you should be able just to put it in a container and make the text align to the right or left, let me know how it goes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it didn't work :(